# C++ variadic template with non-type parameters of different types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I would like to define a class which takes a list of non-type parameters, potentially of different types. For example, the following should be valid:

```
Test<3, 4.5, 6> t;
```

If all parameters had the same type, say `int`, I could use the following definition:

```
template<int... args>
class Test {
  // ...
};
```

To be more specific, in my specific use case there is a second class `Base` with a number of members, and I would like to pass `Base` member pointers.

```
Test<&Base::a, &Base::b>
```

If `Base::a` and `Base::b` have a common type `T`, then I could define `Test` as follows.

```
template<int Base::* ...args>
class Test {
  //
};
```

How can I go about defining such a class `Test`?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I think the best you can get is to use `std::integral_constant` or something similar and use a pack of type template-parameters. You can then use a macro to reduce the boilerplace, e.g.: `#define C_MEM_FUN(X) std::integral_constant<decltype(X), X>` and then `Test<C_MEM_FUN(&Base::a), C_MEM_FUN(&Base::b)>`

Comment: I think `template<Base::* ...args>` should be `template<T Base::* ...args>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
template <class... Types>
struct Wrapper
{
    template <Types... args>
    class Test {
        // ...
    };
};
```

Note that simple notation `template <class... Types, Types... args> class Test;` is not permitted by standard (see paragraph [temp.param] 14.1/15).

Example of using (note that `float`, `double` and `long double` constants can not be non-type template parameters):

```
Wrapper<int, char, unsigned>::Test<1, '2', 3U> t;
```

More specific case with pointers to members can be implemented similarly:

```
struct Base
{
    int a;
    float b;
    void c() {}
};

template <class... Types>
struct Wrapper
{
    template <Types Base::*... args>
    class Test {
        //
    };
};
```

Example of using:

```
Wrapper<int, float, void ()>::Test<&Base::a, &Base::b, &Base::c> t2;
```

This notation can be shortened using variadic macro and `decltype` keyword.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your remark about ```decltype```? It would be ideal if I can drop the list of types after ```Wrapper``` since they are redundant.

Comment: The simplest way I know is in the style of `std::make_tuple` - deduce the types with argument-dependent lookup. With that said, I read that `make_tuple` may not be long for this world, something about it being antithetical to the conventions of C++. You would expect the constructor arguments of `template<class... T> X(T&&...)` to deduce `X<T...>`, but then ADL would have to lookup a type from its own constructor, where the ctor exists before the type is instantiated. You'd need a general opt-in and/or a way to designate the constructor(s) to deduce from - all of which could be in the works.

Comment: Personally, I'd like `friend` constructors to be the syntax. I tried making a `friend` factory, but I stopped short when I realized that my implementation was headed toward using `std::integral_constant`s, and that it was probably intractable if the std library authors used the template signature they did.