# How to select a specialization by non-type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to define a variadic template class with non-type parameters and use a nested template class for which I could to get a specialization by one of variadic template parameters.

My question is similar to [C++ variadic template with non-type parameters of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674347/c-variadic-template-with-non-type-parameters-of-different-types). But I would like to make a specialization for a nested class one of the parameters of the owner class

```
struct Data
{
    std::string field1;
    std::string field2;
    bool field3 = false;
    int field4 = 0;
};

template <typename ... Types>
struct Wrapper
{
    template <Types ... Args>
    struct Holder
    {
    };
};
```

It's valid:

```
using W = Wrapper<decltype(&Data::field1), decltype(&Data::field2), decltype(&Data::field3), decltype(&Data::field4)>;
    using H = W::Holder<&Data::field1, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr>;
```

But I need to use this as

```
using H = W::Holder<&Data::field3>;
```

How can I implement this?

The similar code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct Data
{
    std::string field1;
    std::string field2;
    bool field3 = false;
    int field4 = 0;
};

struct Null;

template <typename T, T>
struct Holder
{
};

template <typename H, typename ... T>
struct Select
    : Select <T ... >
{
    using Base = Select <T ... >;
    using Base::Get;

    template <H F>
    static Holder<H, F> Get();
};

template <>
struct Select<Null>
{
    static void Get();
};

int main()
{
    using S = Select<std::string Data::*, bool Data::*, int Data::*, Null>;
    using H = decltype(S::Get<&Data::field3>());
    static_assert(std::is_same<H, Holder<decltype(&Data::field3), &Data::field3>>::value, "Problem ...");
    return 0;
};
```

But I need do this without decltype and functions

The right solution will be

```
using H = W::Holder<&Data::field3>;
```

Comment: For starters this is ambiguous, `&Data::field1` and `&Data::field2` have the same type, so there's no way to accomplish what you want. Also, it might be beneficial to actually describe the problem you want to solve, might be a better way than the path you're going down here.

Comment: Yes, I was a little mistaken. All types are unique.using W = Wrapper<std::string Data::*, bool Data::*, int Data::*>; The problem is to choose an entity specialization by the value of the one of parameter types

Comment: @NirFriedman whatcha you talking about? Posted code compiles as is.

Comment: @n.m. My bad, you're right. Still, I think the "describe the actual problem" observation stands.

Comment: Hmm, can you specify version? Without 17 this is tricky, can't specify both the type and value of a function pointer (or similar) in a single argument to a template parameter. 17's `template <auto P>` makes that possible.

Comment: It's a similar code

Comment: Do you maybe just want a `std::variant`? Are you familiar with it?

Comment: I would not recommend using C++ 11 if it is simpler to do in C++ 17... Do you really want to write hard to maintain code that is already obsolete according to the current standard.

Comment: @Dmitry Please fix your question instead of saying you made mistakes down here.

Answer (score 0):

For you didn't specify the standard revision, I assume you have no preferences. Well, in C++17 you can do this:

```
template<typename Type>
struct Base {
    template <Type>
    struct Holder {};
};

template <typename ... Types>
struct Wrapper: Base<Types>... {
    template<auto Arg>
    using Holder = typename Base<decltype(Arg)>::template Holder<Arg>;
};
```

At least as long as it stands your comment:

> All types are unique: `using W = Wrapper<std::string Data::*, bool Data::*, int Data::*>;`

The following just works as expected:

```
using W = Wrapper<decltype(&Data::field1), decltype(&Data::field3), decltype(&Data::field4)>;
using H = W::Holder<&Data::field3>;
```

See it on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6zak6NXoxha5qc3F).

Comment: gcc 6.2.0 with -std=c++17 'error: ‘auto’ parameter not permitted in this context'. I'd like on C++11

Comment: @Dmitry it's c++1z with gcc 6, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), non-type values passed to a template must have a fixed type.  This type can depend on previous type parameters, but it must be fixed by them.

You want to pass the non-type parameter as the first argument and give it a variable type.

There is no "template overload resolution" option that is available.

There are other tricks, such tag dispatching to macros or whatever, that could also solve your problem.  But you have specified that you want exactly that syntax.

Your problem is over constrained, and cannot be solved as stated.

So you are out of luck.  Upgrade the version of your compiler and try again later, or remove needless constraints in your next question.